# Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected spaces with $X \times Y$ the product topology, then $X \times Y$ is connected. Does the converse of this hold?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I did problem Problem $3.84$, its easy but I am not sure whether the converse holds or not. It looks like it wont hold, but how do I show/prove it?

I did it in this way but I am not sure whether its ok or not. Can someone verify my proof?

[image]

Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Please edit the title so that it **actually says what you are asking.**

Comment: done, pls check.

Comment: Thanks. Had you done it from the start, it would have saved me some confusion (and Kavi Rama Murthy the effort to react on a—now deleted—comment from me that purely resulted from my confusion caused by the title). So in the future, please be aware that the title matters.

Comment: I am so sorry, this wont happen again. i promise.

Comment: @celtschk You could also have taken 30 seconds to read the actual question and not just the title. Don't act as if you were blameless.

Answer (score 2):

For Problem 3.85: Continuous image of  a connected space is connected. Just apply this to the projection maps $p(x,y)=x$ and $q(x,y)=y$

Comment: what's continuous image? Are you trying to say that the cartesian product of two connected spaces are connected ?

Comment: I am showing that the converse is true. It is given that $X \times Y$ is connected and we have to show that $X$ and $Y$ are connected. The following Theorem is standard and it is also easy to prove from the definition: If $Z$ and $W$ are topological spaces, $f: Z \to W$ is a continuous map such that $f(Z)=W$ and if $Z$ is connected then so is $W$. I am applying this theorem to $Z=X \times Y$ and $W=X, f=p$ to show that $X$ is connected. Similarly, using $q$ I see that $Y$ is connected. @Math_Is_Fun

Comment: Everything is fine if the empty space is disconnected, as I think it should be under the right definition. However, if the empty space is considered to be connected, then there is a trivial counterexample, where $X$ is empty and $Y$ is a nonempty disconnected space.

Comment: @bof I have never seen anyone treating empty set as a topological space.

Comment: The definition at the Wikipedia page for [Topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_neighbourhoods) explicitly says "We allow $X$ to be empty."

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy And yet the empty space is a perfectly fine topological space.

Comment: I didn't understand your proof well, but  I was thinking of proving this in a different way than just using projection maps.